# Error with VS2008 trying to debug WCF service

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf

Pulled down an old revision of a project from subversion, made some changes, and rebuilt it.  Now VS2008 errors out when i try to debug it with this error:

[alt text http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/5531/erroro.png](http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/5531/erroro.png)

It doesnt even hit my service ctor, and it indicates a invalid configuration file, but its the same when comparing against my current revision.  Anyone seen an error like this?

All the searching i have done has indicated this is an issue with vs2005, but Im running 2008.

edit:

I had an old referenced dll in the windows assembly.  Even though I specified the dll in the bin, directory, upon rebuild, VS for some reason switched to the assembly in the GAC.  Removing the old assembly from the GAC fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the service contract in your assembly, and the accompanying config file? Can you also post the command line used to invoke WcfSvcHost? I don't guess you've used that in VS2005 to debug (since it was only released with VS2008) - maybe there's something wrong there.

At first glance, it looks like the service type referenced in the config file probably isn't available in the service assembly.

Marc

Comment: In a roundabout way that is what it was.  I had an old referenced dll in the windows assembly.  Even though I specified the dll in the bin, directory, upon rebuild, VS for some reason switched to the assembly in the GAC.  Removing the old assembly from the GAC fixed the issue.